# vaadin6+spring: add custom component to application

Tags: spring, vaadin

when I use this code the result is empty page:

```
public class Vaadin6biuApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        xx a = new xx();
           Window w = new Window("aness conf");
           w.addComponent(a);
           setMainWindow(w);
    }  
}

public class xx extends CustomComponent {
    @AutoGenerated
    private AbsoluteLayout mainLayout;
    @AutoGenerated
    private Button button_1;
    public xx() {
        buildMainLayout();
        setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);
    }
    @AutoGenerated
    private AbsoluteLayout buildMainLayout() {
        mainLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
        mainLayout.setImmediate(false);
        button_1 = new Button();
        mainLayout.addComponent(button_1, "top:100.0px;left:100.0px;");         
        return mainLayout;
    }  
}
```

how to add custom component to application?
thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [wiki tutorial](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Spring+Integration) for vaadin6 + spring? With spring > 2.5 it's fairly simple:

```
@Configurable(preConstruction = true)
public class SpringHelloWorld extends com.vaadin.Application {

@Autowired
private MyBeanInterface bean;

public void init() {
    final Window main = new Window("Hello window");
    setMainWindow(main);        
    main.addComponent(new Label( bean.myMethod() ));
}
}
```